# Manipulate a LaTeX2e counter with LaTeX3

Tags: best-practices, expl3

I have some `expl3` code where I want to manipulate a counter which is defined by a package using LaTeX2e code.

If I want to manipulate the counter `foo`, I could either mixing up LaTeX2e code with LaTeX3 code:

```
% some expl3 code
\addtocounter{foo}{123}
% more expl3 code
```

or I could do it using only `expl3` commands:

```
% some expl3 code
\int_gadd:Nn \c@foo { 123 }
% more expl3 code
```

Which way of manipulating the counter is preferable? Or does it not matter which way I choose?

**Edit:** Here is a MWE, using the `datenumber` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber,xparse}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \juhu_futuredate:n #1
{
  \setdatetoday
  \int_gadd:Nn \c@datenumber { #1 } % \addtocounter{datenumber}{#1}
  \setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}
  In ~ #1 ~ days ~ is ~ \datedate.
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\futuredate}{m}
{
  \juhu_futuredate:n { #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\futuredate{7}

\end{document}
```

The `datenumber` package defines the `datenumber` counter and assigns an integer to it with the `\setdatetoday` command. `\datedate` prints a date depending on the value given to `\setdatebynumber`. Of course, I could define an own integer and pass it to the `\setdatebynumber` command, but the integer given by `\setdatetoday` is nontrivial and I want to avoid to do the calculations on my own.

Comment: I think answers to this question will depend on how you're implementing this.  A MWE might help.  And then, depending on the context there will most likely be a wide variety of opinion.  But without a MWE, you're only likely to get very general answers.

Comment: My general advice would be to try to build an interface between the old and the new that will allow you to keep the two syntaxes separate.  Then again, without a MWE it's hard to explain how to do this (or whether it's appropriate or feasible for what you have in mind).

Comment: `\addtocounter{foo}{123}` just checks that the counter is defined and, in case it is, it globally adds the value, so there's not much difference with `\int_gadd:cn {c@foo}{123}`. There is a *big* difference with `\stepcounter{foo}`, because this doesn't simply step the counter, but also zeroes the counters associated to `foo`.

Comment: Hmmm.  The question I'm left with is "why are you even bothering with `expl3`?"  It seems like `xparse` would be all that you really need.  You're hardly doing much of anything with `expl3`.  Perhaps that's the nature of your MWE.  But your MWE isn't really showing any need for `expl3`.

Comment: @A.Ellett My MWE is very minimal. There is some more `expl3` code in my actual LaTeX file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess I can provide a more-or-less 'official' answer: use the LaTeX2e commands. Mixing up the two interfaces is asking for trouble, and while we are working on several areas we've not got a 'user level' counter approach at yet. (Indeed, the entire question of how variables at the document-level should be handled is open.)

The reason I'd use `\setcounter` here is that `\c@...` is an *internal* for LaTeX2e, and the entire point of `expl3` is to have clear interfaces and internals. There's no reason to abuse the interfaces here (no functionality gain), so stick with them.

Answer (score 7):

**First** I would avoid using internal commands if at all possible:  particularly when there is already an interface provided.  So for example, I would use

```
\addtocounter{datenumber}{...}
```

instead of working directly with

```
\c@datenumber
```

**Also,** I would use `\addtocounter` with counters provided at the LaTeX user-interface level.  I would use `\int_gadd:Nn` only for counter-like things defined with `expl3`.

**Next,** I would not mix `@` notation with `expl3` notation.  If you must use both, I would clearly separate the two and create an interface if they must somehow share information.  But if at all possible, I would try to avoid the mixing of the two, even with an interface.

**Then** I would create my own set of `expl3` commands to interactly directly with those provided by any particular package.  Within these commands, I would only use standard LaTeX macros/structures and any LaTeX macros/structures provided by packages for the user interface.

**Finally,** I would create the `expl3` code that *on the surface* is purely `expl3` code.

So, following the above recommendation, your MWE would become something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber,xparse}

\makeatletter
%% define/work with functions that use `@` 
%% notation create an interface for these  
%% functions if necessary.                 
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
%% User level interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\futuredate}{m}
{
  \juhu_futuredate:n { #1 }
}

%% Internal `expl3` code that on the surface remains purely `expl3`
%% Though these functions might "stand in" for non-expl3 code.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \juhu_futuredate:n #1
{
  %% ... expl3 code ...
  \_juhu_initialize_date:
  %% ... expl3 code ...
  \_juhu_advance_date_by:n {#1}
  %% ... expl3 code ...
  \_juhu_reset_by_datenumber:
  %% ... expl3 code ...
  \_juhu_print_future_date:n {#1}
  %% ... expl3 code ...
}

%% Interface with commands from `datenumber` package
\cs_new_protected:Nn  \_juhu_initialize_date:       {\setdatetoday}
\cs_new_protected:Nn  \_juhu_reset_by_datenumber:   {\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}}  
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_juhu_advance_date_by:n #1   {\addtocounter{datenumber}{#1}}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_juhu_print_future_date:n #1 {In ~ #1 ~ days ~ is ~ \datedate}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\futuredate{7}

\end{document}
```