# Treatment applied in parallel to `LaTeX3`'s integers and `LaTeX2e`'s counter gives differents results

Tags: align, counters, labels, expl3, latex3

I'm in the process to try to give an `expl3` flavor of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397638/18401) of my question: [Add a marginal note when a page break occurs in the middle of a multi-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/396833/18401).

During this process, I noticed a difference in the result of some treatment applied in parallel to `LaTeX3`'s integers and `LaTeX2e`'s counters: the minimized example below shows that, despite the parallelism of the treatment,
the labels affected to each line of the `align` environment:

- start from `0` for the labels build with a `LaTeX2` counter,
- start from `n` for the labels build with a `LaTeX3` integer (`n` being the number of labeled lines of the `align` environment),

the `.aux` file containing:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{LaTeX2-counter-line-1}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX3-integer-line-4}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX2-counter-line-2}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX3-integer-line-5}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX2-counter-line-3}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX3-integer-line-6}{{}{1}}
```

Do you see what's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

% Each line of the `align' environment will have a unique number.
\newcounter{line@of@align}
\int_new:N \g_line_of_align_int

% Save the original `align' environment.
\cs_set_eq:cc {db_align_start:} {align}
\cs_set_eq:cc {db_align_end:} {endalign}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{amsmathalign}{}
{\db_align_start:}
{\db_align_end:}

% Redefine it.
\RenewEnviron{align}
{
  \db_patch:nV {align} \BODY
}

\seq_new:N \l_db_patch_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \db_patch:nn
 {
  %
   \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_db_patch_seq { \\ } { #2 }
   \begin{amsmathalign}
     \seq_use:Nnnn \l_db_patch_seq { \db@patch } { \db@patch } { \db@patch } \hfill
   \end{amsmathalign}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \db_patch:nn { nV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\db@patch}{so}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\\*[#2]}{\\[#2]}%
  }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\\*}{\\}
  }%
  % We increment the number of the current line.
  \stepcounter{line@of@align}%
  \int_gincr:N \g_line_of_align_int
  % We set the labels of the current line.
  \ltx@label{ LaTeX2-counter-line-\theline@of@align }%
  \ltx@label{ LaTeX3-integer-line-\int_use:N \g_line_of_align_int }%
}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  1 + 1 & = 2 \\
  2 + 1 & = 3 \\
  3 + 1 & = 4 \\
  4 + 1 & = 5
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AMS alignments are set twice, once in a "measuring" pass and then again to typeset. It knows about all LaTeX2e counters (using the infrastructure that LaTeX uses to reset counters for `\include` so all counters are restored after the measuring, but it does not know about expl3 allocation so those counters all get incremented on both passes. You would see a similar thing with `tabularx` and some other environments.

---

Perhaps the simplest fix is to use a hybrid allocation of the count register

```
%\int_new:N \g_line_of_align_int
\newcounter{g_line_of_align_int}
\cs_set_eq:NN\g_line_of_align_int\c@g_line_of_align_int
```

produces

```
\relax 
\newlabel{LaTeX2-counter-line-1}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX3-integer-line-1}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX2-counter-line-2}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX3-integer-line-2}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX2-counter-line-3}{{}{1}}
\newlabel{LaTeX3-integer-line-3}{{}{1}}
```

---

The dual allocation is one general approach to the problem but for the specific case of AMS alignments rather than making sure the counter gets reset it would be better to only increment it once  so

```
  \ifmeasuring@\else % do nothing on first pass
  \stepcounter{line@of@align}%
  \int_gincr:N \g_line_of_align_int
  % We set the labels of the current line.
  \ltx@label{ LaTeX2-counter-line-\theline@of@align }%
  \ltx@label{ LaTeX3-integer-line-\int_use:N \g_line_of_align_int
  \fi
```

Comment: I think it isn't really recommended to use `c@` internal in LaTeX3. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167094/manipulate-a-latex2e-counter-with-latex3 -- Perhaps `\int_set:Nn\g_line_...int{\arabic{g_line..._int}}` is better?
 (also you have an unmatched `(` in the answer)